# Leaflet onEachFeature table info into a Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to get a table from a `geojson` extracted with `onEachFeature` function, it works displaying it with an alert, but I tried `getElementsByClassName`,to get it inside a Div but nothing shows

I'm using leaflet with leaflet sidebar plugin

Thanks

```
var tbl1 = "";

var proy = L.geoJSON(json_Obras, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) { 
        tbl1 = '<table><tr><th scope="row">OBRA </th><td>' + (feature.properties['OBRA'] !== null ?     Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['OBRA'])) : '') + '</td></tr>'

    }
}).addTo(map);


proy.on('click', function () {
    sidebar.show();

})
map.on('click', function () {
    sidebar.hide();
});

document.getElementsByClassName('t1').innerHTML = tbl1;
```

The div displays with a button click

```
<input id="btn" class="gral" type="button" name="answer" value="DATA" />
            <div id="tabla" class="t1" style="display:none;">
            </div>
```

jquery click function

```
$('.gral').click(function() {
      $('.t1').toggle('slow', function() {

      });
    });
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to find out how to do this, based on a [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201987/leaflet-sidebar-set-content-depending-on-clicked-geojson-feature?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar', {
            closeButton: false,
            position: 'left'
        });

map.addControl(sidebar);

var ptsty = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            click: openSidebar 
         });
     }

var lay1 = L.geoJson(json_Obras,{
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, ptsty)
    },
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);


 function openSidebar(e) {
        sidebar.toggle();
        sidebar.setContent('<div id="sidebarin"><h2>' + e.target.feature.properties.OBRA + '</h2></div>');
    }
```

Comment: The table you are generating  is wrong way. at each iteration you are assigning the full table to the tbl1 variable.

Comment: You're right, any advice?

Comment: in the toggle callback check if the div is showing then place  document.getElementsByClassName('t1').innerHTML = tbl1; else empty;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are setting content of your div before the callback onEachFeature gets called. So the content is empty. Instead it is better to add content directly to element (sidebar or div), or add it when you toggle the sidebar.

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    var popupContent = "<p>I started out as a GeoJSON " +
     feature.geometry.type + ", but now I'm a Leaflet vector!</p>";

    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
      popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
    }
    $('#sidebar>.sidebar_content').html(popupContent);
    $('.custom-div').html(popupContent);
}
```

[I have prepared small demo which is working and you can get an idea how it can be implemented.](https://jsbin.com/kajocuxowi/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot to connect the geojson info to the sidebar, but it only displays the values of the last point feature in my geojson, it doesn't iterate

Comment: Just use $('#sidebar>.sidebar_content').append(popupContent); instead of $('#sidebar>.sidebar_content').html(popupContent);
or save your markup into an array.

Comment: I tried, but it shows the whole list, I tried an iteration: var info = [];
        for (var prop in feature.properties) {
            info.push(prop + " : " + feature.properties[prop]);
        }                                                                                               that works fine with layer.bindPopup, but when I bind it to the jQuery code with .append it shows the whole list, and with .html it shows only the last feature

Comment: It seems like you want to display an info for a feature that has been clicked? In this case, you need to add content to feature itself (or store it in a map by feature key/id). And update the content of your sidebar when its clicked using .html() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the concatenation like this.

```js
var tbl1 = '<table><tr><th scope="row">OBRA </th></tr>';

var proy = L.geoJSON(json_Obras, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) { 
        tbl1 += '<tr><td>' + (feature.properties['OBRA'] !== null ?     Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['OBRA'])) : '') + '</td></tr>'

    }
}).addTo(map);
tbl1 += '</table>';
```

jQuery click function

```
$('.gral').click(function() {
  $('.t1').toggle('slow', function() {
     if($(this).is(":visible")){
       document.getElementsByClassName('t1').innerHTML = tbl1;
     }else{

     }
  });
});
```